# C# PropertyGrid => How to change visible Properties at Runtime

Tags: c#

I have to following problem,

In a map-editor you can place "Joints" (FarseerPhysics) on objects, there are 23 types of joints (in an enum). The joints are all pretty much the same (just 1-2 new properties per jointtype). I want to enable the user to change the joints using a WinForm PropertyGrid.
So if the user changes the property "JointType" (the enum), the PropertyGrid needs to hide the old properties and show the new ones, is there a way to achieve that?
(All properties of all Joints are saved in ONE class called JointItem, I just need to dynamically show/hide some of them)

Comment: I didnt try anything since I have no idea (I just found the attribute Browsable in the net)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no simple to use built-in support in `PropertyGrid` for dynamically altering which properties are visible depending on the value of another property. This doesn't mean it can't be done, just that it takes a bit of work.

As you've already discovered, what controls whether a property is visible or not is the `BrowsableAttribute`. So basically you need to change this attribute dynamically, and the way to do that is to create your own `TypeProvider` and `TypeDescriptor` for your class, that dynamically returns the `Browsable(false)` or `Browsable(true)` attribute for the property to be hidden/shown depending on the value of another property in the class.  I will not attempt to describe how `TypeProvider` and `TypeDescriptor` works here, since it is quite a lengthy subject and there is much information readily available on this subject on the web already.

In addition you need to specify the `[RefreshProperties(RefreshProperties.All)]` attribute on the property controlling whether another property should be visible or not. This will force the propertygrid to requery the `TypeDescriptor` for the list of properties whenever its value is changed, giving your `TypeDescriptor` the chance to return a different set of properties, or different attributes on the properties it returns.

I hope this at least points you in the right direction. Unfortunately it takes a quite bit of work to glue these things together.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a method for changing the Browsable attribute of a property in your JointItem class:

```
private void ChangeBrowsability(object pThis, string pProperty, bool pBrowsable)
{
    PropertyDescriptor pdDescriptor = TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(pThis.GetType())[pProperty];
    BrowsableAttribute baAttribute = (BrowsableAttribute)pdDescriptor.Attributes[typeof(BrowsableAttribute)];
    FieldInfo fiBrowsable = baAttribute.GetType().GetField("browsable", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);
    fiBrowsable.SetValue(baAttribute, pBrowsable);
}
```

Then you could have a big long if then else sequence or the likes:

```
JointItem jiThis = WhereEverYouGetYourJointItemFrom();
if (jiThis.JointType == eJoinType.Elbow)
{
    ChangeBrowsability(jiThis, "JointAngle", true);
    ChangeBrowsability(jiThis, "MinAngle", true);
    ChangeBrowsability(jiThis, "MaxAngle", true);
    ChangeBrowsability(jiThis, "ScrewType", false);
    //...
}
else ...
```

Of course you need your dose of "using"s!

```
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Reflection;
```